# iPhoto not launching after upgrading to OS X 10.10, Yosemite

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, photos.app

Ever since I migrated to a new Macbook Pro Retina (MacBookPro11,2) and to OS X 10.10, iPhoto won't run.

I was running OS X 10.8 on a Macbook Pro (MacBookPro7,1) before. I have tried uninstalling iPhoto and reinstalling using the App Store.

The error I receive is this, [full crash log](https://www.dropbox.com/s/7vm08rs0ed4fwdw/iphoto-error.txt?dl=0):

```
Exception Type:        EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000002, 0x0000000000000000

Application Specific Information:
dyld: launch, loading dependent libraries

Dyld Error Message:
  Library not loaded: /Library/Frameworks/NyxAudioAnalysis.framework/Versions/A/NyxAudioAnalysis
  Referenced from: /Applications/iPhoto.app/Contents/Frameworks/iLifeSlideshow.framework/Versions/A/iLifeSlideshow
  Reason: image not found
```

From what I can tell, there are certain libraries that can't be loaded. Apparently, simply reinstalling iPhoto does not do the trick. Is there anything else I can do?

Comment: Looking at your crash log, have you checked Software Update for an update to "iLife Support"? It seems it is crashing because it can't load the Nyx framework.

Comment: I'm guessing it's an old version too - references to Cocoa in that. Without knowing for sure, wouldn't an Apple app be entirely Carbon by now? Still guessing… Build Info:            iPhotoProject-910… iPhoto 9.1, circa 2010?

Comment: Sounds about right, yes. I checked the App Store and Software Update, but couldn't find iLife Support. iMovie and GarageBand run fine. What to do?

Comment: iLife 11 apps should update through the App Store, even though they are from before the Store itself. Do a search in the store & see if it wants you to pay for it. If so, you might have to ask Apple; they've been known to 'unlock' apps in those circumstances.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, @Tetsujin. This is not the issue, though. I can see iPhoto available in the App Store, and it lets me update for free. After updating, "Get Info" in the Finder shows me that I have version 9.6 installed.

Comment: & it still crashes & still shows 910... in the version string in the crash dump? Have you tried moving the database out of its expected location, see if it will launch 'bare'? or hold Opt as you launch it, which will ask you to choose a library, including 'new', as a test.

Comment: Just tried both - nothing. It immediately crashes with the message: iPhoto kann aufgrund eines Problems nicht geöffnet werden. (translates to "iPhoto can't be opened due to a problem.") Do you think I should try installing this: http://support.apple.com/kb/DL842?viewlocale=de_DE&locale=de_DE and see whether it will be updated through the App Store?

Comment: I just tried the iLife Support image from the link above. It won't even let me install those files, saying that I already have a newer version of the software installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a proper solution to this problem:

I had used the Migration Assistant to migrate my old Mac System (10.8 or so) to a newly bought Mac Mini with 10.10 (Yosemite). After a few day I found out that iPhoto wasn’t starting — with the described symptoms.

Fortunately I still have the old system running, so I could compare them and copying the old NyxAudioAnalysis directory did the job.

Everything could be fine here, but I wondered why when reparing my access rights the disk utility kept telling me there was a problem with the directory. It said it was a directory, but was expected to be a symbolic link:

```
Abweichende Zugriffsrechte für „Library/Frameworks/NyxAudioAnalysis.framework“, Soll-Wert: lrwxr-xr-x , Ist-Wert: drwxr-xr-x .
```

<sup>(German version here, sorry.)</sup>

Since I have another box running under Yosemite I could compare the systems and I found out that Apple had moved the location of the NyxAudioAnalysis framework at some time. In 10.10 (Yosemite) it is located in `/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks`, whereas in older systems it was in `/Library/Frameworks`. To ensure compatibility, Apple inserted a symlink at the old location: `NyxAudioAnalysis.framework` → `/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/NyxAudioAnalysis.framework`. The migration assistant seems to have messed that up somehow.

So to fix it you can use Terminal.app:

```
cd /Library/Frameworks
sudo mv NyxAudioAnalysis.framework NyxAudioAnalysis.framework.copy
sudo ln -s /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/NyxAudioAnalysis.framework NyxAudioAnalysis.framework
```

which does the job.

Conclusion: Copying the directory from some source is working, but it may not last. The potential problem with it is that if Apple should update their library some time you won’t get the changes. This could cause some problems with iPhoto (or other programs) any time in the future. Therefore I suggest to insert the original symbolic link.

Comment: Thanks, I can see how this is a better solution to the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find a blog post online where someone had uploaded the missing libraries. I just put them in /Library/Frameworks/ and iPhoto now opens up fine. Here is a link to the blog post:

http://www.sanebutdifferent.com/iphoto-11-nyxaudioanalysis-crash-error